# Inheriting class properties from parent class after initialize sets value

Tags: php, class, cakephp, inheritance, cakephp-2.8

Trying to make a component that will allow utilizing more than one payment gateway (Yes, I realize it's been done before).  I created a 'PaymentsComponent', and some gateway-specific components that extend it.

The problem is, I can't get the variables set/initialized in the parent component to be accessible in the child.  They ARE accessible, but only with the default value, not with the value after initializing.  What am I missing?

**Within a Controller:**

```
private function processPayment($requestData) {
    $this->Payments = $this->Components->load('Payments');
    $this->Payments->initialize($this);
    debug($this->Payments->apiSecretKey); // shows: '123456789'
    $result = $this->Payments->charge($requestData);
    //...
}
```

**PaymentsComponent**

```
<?php
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
class PaymentsComponent extends Component {

    public $apiSecretKey = null;

    public function initialize() {
        $this->apiSecretKey = Configure::read('PaymentGateway.secret_key');
    }

    public function charge($data) {
        $result = $this->Authnet->charge($data);
    }
    // ...
}
```

**Authorize.net Component**

```
class AuthNetComponent extends PaymentsComponent {
    public $components = array('Session');
    public function charge($data) {
        debug($this->apiSecretKey); // shows: null
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why is everything public? Why do the classes inherit at least three levels deep? Why don't I see any constructor, dependency injection, separation of concerns? `$result = $this->Authnet->charge($data);` in the PaymentsComponent does not make sense, because it assumes that Authnet is a SEPARATE object that does not inherit from PaymentsComponent. It looks like it might implement the strategy pattern, which is a good idea.

Comment: I welcome general suggestions, but more importantly, welcome an answer.

Comment: I've done basically the same before in 1.3 and it is a pain and *huge* amount of work if done properly. Testing is a huge time killer here because you can't rely on unit tests alone. I've started writing my own lib years ago (https://github.com/phppayments) but finally ended up using https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay Honestly, my best suggestion is to use Omnipay, it's not perfect but good enough and will save you A LOT time and trouble. Also I don't think a component is right for this. Create your own set of classes and pass the request / response object to the constructor.